# angular - show notification based on HTTP response

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I use middleware for my back-end which processes each exception and produces JSON response which looks as follows:

```
{"error":"System.Exception: 'You must be logged in to perform this action.'"}
```

In my Angular app I would like to show a **notification** carrying the exception text each time the exception occurs, but I'm not entirely sure about how to implement this.

I wonder if should use `HttpInterceptor` for that - I'm also not quire sure how to register them properly - they should be registered in `root.module.ts` to work app-wide, right?

Could someone recommend a workaround or provide code examples please?

Comment: do you want to use intercepter??

Comment: @UnluckyAj yes, provided that it's the best approach

Comment: yes thats true because  you can handle all notification type from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use an interceptor.

Start by creating a service and transform it to an interceptor :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {
  HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
      .catch(err => { /* Display your error here */})
      .handle(req);
  }
}
```

Next, you will need to provide it in your module :

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor, multi: true },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

http-intercepter.ts

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHeaders,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppService } from './../../core/services/citizen/app-services/app.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private appService: AppService) {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param req - parameter to handle http request
     * @param next - parameter for http handler
     */
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const started = Date.now();
        /**
         * Handle newly created request with updated header (if given)
         */
        return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            /**
             * Sucessfull Http Response Time.
             */
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
            }

        }, (err: any) => {
            /**
             * redirect to the error_handler route according to error status or error_code
             * or show a modal
             */
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                switch (err.status) {
                    case 0:
                        console.log("Error type 0")
                        break;
                    case 400:
                        console.log("Error type 400")
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        console.log("Error type 401")
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

in module.ts:

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true },
  ]
```